# Regular Expression Identities list?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I have been working on problems to simplify or equate certain regular expressions to others but so far the list of identities I have found in my textbook (Sipser) doesn’t tell me enough to simplify complex regular expressions. Is there a comprehensive list of identities that I can find somewhere?

For example I am currently stuck at trying to simplify/expand an expression of the form $(R^*S)^*$ but haven’t found a way to do so.

Comment: See [Proving that all regular expressions are reachable via algebraic laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426423).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thanks, that makes sense